# Why laravel events also stored in the jobs table when i dispatch and run artisan queue:work?

Tags: php, laravel-5, events, queue

I created a jobs **CallImportScript** that calls a artisan command **ImportScript**. Inside this ImportScript, i have an event that trigger **UpdateCronlog**, basically to display a logs. The problem is when the worker execute the queue it store also the UpdateCronlog in the jobs table.

**CallImportScript.php**

```
public function handle()
{
    Artisan::call("ImportScript"); 
}
```

**ImportScript.php**

```
//some loop
for() {
    //ongoing process in the database

    // need to trigger the event after database process
    event(new UpdateCronlog('some string'));
}
```

The problem is it doesnt call the event right away, instead it goes to the jobs table. its like it also queque.

Answer (score 1):

Check your .env file. What do you have set for QUEUE_CONNECTION=? It is probably DATABASE, If it attempts to write to the jobs table. Setting it to sync won't do this. Read up on queue drivers and pick the one you need for your project. Redis is also an option depending on what you need. Hope this helps :)